# No posts or images after Wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress

I developped a Wordpress website on a local server using Wamp and Mysql 5.7.
I migrated it to dardhiafa.tn and nothing seems to work .. the doesn't load properly and there is no posts that show up. 
I did migrate it manually and also using Duplicator and the same result.
Any solution ?

Comment: Check your .htaccess file or your URL in the database. Because your site looking for  http://localhost/dardhiafa/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/piscine-le-soir.jpg

Comment: I guess you don't changed URL in the database for all your files.

Comment: I changed all the URLs and nothing sees to work ! ! any other solution ?

Comment: I guess because i worked with a page builder (Goodlayer) to create pages in wordpress ..

Comment: the last version of Duplicator work very well, BUT don't chance all the link inside the css and js page! I don't know how in some page yes and in other no, but you need to check your files and change manually. I use page builder and change all links inside, with Goodlayer i don't know. But have a really good customer service.